# ColdFusion and AJAX - GET 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm trying to learn how to do fairly simple tasks with ColdFusion, jQuery, and AJAX but have ran into a problem that I have not been able to figure out.

For this proof-of-concept, I created simple, fake data. The table in the database consists of just 3 fields (ID, name, and rating). On the "main" page I have this data displayed in a table with the "rating" being a drop-down input. I'm trying to use AJAX to update the "rating" when the user changes the value.

As far as the jQuery side goes, I have two variables that are assigned to the "changed" ID and its new rating. I have the following code inside the "change" function (which is working fine itself):
`$.post('update.cfc', {ID: inputID, rating: selRat})`

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="updateRating" access="remote" output="false">

        <cfquery datasource="#session.db#" name="update">
            UPDATE ajaxTest
            SET rating = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#FORM.rating#">
            WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#FORM.ID#">
        </cfquery>

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

When I go to the page and change a value, I get the following error in the Console (while the path won't make sense, it is pointing to the correct location):
[image: Console Error Message]

It very well may be something simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Not related to your question, but the fact that your function is using session and form variables strikes me as fundamentally wrong.  Those values should be passed to your function as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should post to `update.cfc?method=updateRating` via jQuery.

Then add `ID` and `rating` as `<cfargument>` in your function, and reference your variables like they are in `ARGUMENTS` scope, not `FORM`.

Comment: That definitely got me a lot closer to getting it to work, so thank you!

It's now giving me a POST error with a "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: that could indicate something else.  Check Network tab in your chrome's console and see what the ajax request returns.  If it is a 500 from web server, turn off "Enable HTTP status codes" in your CF Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a cftry like this. This will either return EID of 0, if everything passes, or EID of 1 if there's an error, and it will also return the error.

From your previous question regarding this cfc, I recall that I suggested putting it in an isolated folder with its own application.cfc (for easy testing). If you did that, then it might be session.db is tripping you up, for it possibly not being defined. Regardless, this code should clearly define whatever the error is.

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="updateRating" returntype="struct" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="json">
      <cfset local.restruct = structnew()>
      <cfset local.restruct.eid = 0>
      <cftry>
        <cfquery datasource="#session.db#" name="update">
            UPDATE ajaxTest
            SET rating = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#FORM.rating#">
            WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#FORM.ID#">
        </cfquery>
        <cfcatch>
          <cfset local.restruct = cfcatch>
          <cfset local.restruct.eid = 1>
        </cfcatch>
      </cftry>

      <cfreturn local.restruct>
      <!--- If eid returns 0, everything is fine, if it returns 1, error data is returned with it --->
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And, to invoke it with javascript, roughly. Presently this will return basic Alerts() and console.log() but you can make it do whatever you like. It also doesn't actually pass variables in its present state, just flat data

```
$("#formname").submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = "/enter/path/to/file.cfc?method=updateRating";
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : {ID: 1, rating: 3},
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            var pObj = data;
            if (pObj.EID == 1) {
                for(key in pObj) {
                    if (pObj[key].length) {
                        alert(key + ": " + pObj[key]);
                        console.log(key + ": " + pObj[key]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
              alert("success");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails      
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    // e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});
```

Comment: My apologies, I must have missed your suggestion on the previous thread about doing the EID testing. I put it in place but I couldn't find a way to see the result?

Comment: @Steve Oh, no, the eid wasn't previously mentioned, just the bit about session.db. Anyway, I updated my reply with a sample js invocation. You need to change line 1 to the proper id and whatever trigger event, and you'll want to fix the data line.

Comment: @Steve I also have to say that this is for debugging. You could also dump the cfcatch to a file which is more secure for production. I'd still return EID, just not the cfcatch stuff, so that your javascript can make a decision, like notifying of success (EID=0) or error (EID=1).

Comment: I figured it out. Surprise, it wasn't related to what I was asking about. That said, I've definitely learned a lot.

As it turns out, it had to do with my Javascript variable that was storing the ID number.

[Valid] HTML doesn't allow for you to have IDs start with numbers. Because of this, I could not simply put the ID as the entry number. I had to add text before it essentially making the ID of the HTML element "entry#".

This forced me to use Javascript to "extract" only the number in the element's ID. The method I was using to do so was actually returning an array. That was the issue.